# Facing this error The following binaries are missing: ndk-build. Please install them

Tags: android, linphone, ndk-build

I'm trying to build ' linphone-android ' .

[link to git repo](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android)

Somehow i manged to resolv all the bugs but now i'm stuck at when i try to run ' **./prepare.py **' commanad in terminal it giving me NDK ERROR i.e **ERROR: The following binaries are missing: ndk-build. Please install them.**

I have ndk path in .bash file also but unable to resolve this error.

Please share some solution
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you have added android-sdk and android-ndk path in your environment. If not then you can add sdk and ndk path using below command.

```
export PATH=/Users/kaushik512/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/:/Users/kaushik512/Library/Android/sdk/tools/:/Users/kaushik512/Downloads/android-ndk-r12b/:/nobackup/local/prog/nasm/bin:$PATH

export PATH=/opt/local/bin/:$PATH
```

after adding path check using `echo $PATH`.

Add above in PATH and see if issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Do check the version of ndk in your android studio. I was facing the same problem and my ndk version was 16 so I changed it to 15 it worked but also I made the project again and followed the steps one by one as given in the repository, the same link that you have provided.

Hope that helps.