# The following binaries are missing: ndk-build. Please install them

Tags: linphone

I am getting below error while I am trying to build Linphone for Android.

```
# ./prepare.py

' ./prepare.py **' commanad in terminal it giving me NDK ERROR i.e **ERROR: The following binaries are missing: ndk-build. Please install them.
```

How to resolve this? I have added ndk-build in Makefile already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you have added android-sdk and android-ndk path in your environment. If not then you can add sdk and ndk path using below command.

```
export PATH=/Users/kaushik512/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/:/Users/kaushik512/Library/Android/sdk/tools/:/Users/kaushik512/Downloads/android-ndk-r12b/:/nobackup/local/prog/nasm/bin:$PATH

export PATH=/opt/local/bin/:$PATH
after adding path check using echo $PATH.
```

Add above in PATH and see if issue resolved.

This is duplicate question and you can find same question here [Facing this error The following binaries are missing: ndk-build. Please install them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305049/facing-this-error-the-following-binaries-are-missing-ndk-build-please-install/45318318#45318318).

Comment: I have similar issue.. I already added sdk and ndk path at environment variable .. any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I was using Bash on windows and the problem was I was typing into path

```
/ndk
```

instead of

```
/home/{user}/ndk
```

I found my directory with

```
echo $PWD
```

then used

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/ndk
```

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded ndk from: https://developer.android.com/ 
- Extract the ndk compressed file, you will have a ndk folder, you will see a file named: "ndk-build" inside this folder
- This file is what your compiler did not found before.
And that is why you will need to include the file's path into your path.
To do:
export PATH=$PATH:/path_where_you_store_your_ndk

You can then make a check by typing:
echo $PATH
and make sure the ndk folder now is included in your environment path.
Then retry again with ./prepare.py, it should work.