# The following binaries are missing: ndk-build. Linphone

Tags: android, python, android-ndk, linphone, linphone-sdk

I downloaded and added ndk to system environment. I can use ndk-build command in terminal. But still getting this error when executing prepare.py. Can anyone help?
So far I've downloaded and tried ndk 11, 15 and 16 none of them solve the issue.
Platform: Windows 10
Python ver.: 3.6.3

Comment: Not enough info to go by. We have no idea exactly what you've downloaded, where you've extracted it to on your machine, what your build script(s) look like, etc.

Comment: If you are on Windows, the script won't work. Or, maybe you have the up-to-date NDK r16? Linphone works with **r11** to **r15**.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I wasn't aware of that. Apparently linphone-android won't build on Windows. https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/issues/48

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the path of NDK as mentioned in the below link. Maybe it will help and do remember to restart the IDE.
[To set path of ndk in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860608/the-following-binaries-are-missing-ndk-build-please-install-them)