# Building Linphone: ERROR: The following binaries are missing: ndk-build. Please install them

Tags: android, android-ndk, linphone

I'm attempting to build the Linphone app, according the instructions here:

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android

When I run `prepare.py`, I get the following error:

> ERROR: The following binaries are missing: ndk-build. Please install them.

I have my path set to include the NDK folder.  The problem is, there's no `ndk-build.exe` in that folder, or anywhere on my machine.  There's a `ndk-build.cmd` file, but the `prepare.py` is specifically looking for `ndk-build.exe`.

I've downloaded and looked through `android-ndk-r15c-windows-x86_64.zip`, `android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64.zip`, `android-ndk-r17c-windows-x86_64.zip` and `android-ndk-r18b-windows-x86_64.zip` and none of them contain **ndk-build.exe**.

I know I'm missing something, I'm just not sure what it is.

Here's the line from `prepare.py` looking for `ndk-build.exe`:

```
ndk_build = find_executable('ndk-build')
```

Comment: please check this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860608/the-following-binaries-are-missing-ndk-build-please-install-them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860608/the-following-binaries-are-missing-ndk-build-please-install-them)

Comment: Please review this post: [ndk error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860608/the-following-binaries-are-missing-ndk-build-please-install-them)

Answer (score 0):

Remember to set the environment variable **`ANDROID_HOME`**

> Download the latest Android sdk with `platform-tools` and `tools` updated to latest revision, then add both `tools` and `platform-tools` folders in your path and the android-sdk folder to `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable.
>
> Download the latest Android NDK from google and add it to your path (no symlink !!!) and `ANDROID_NDK` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I double checked that my path is set correctly, along with the other system variables.

Comment: To prove that it can find the NDK folder, I renamed ndk-build.cmd to ndk-build.exe and it finds it successfully, which is great except that it's not a valid exe and things go badly after that.

So I'm back to the main question - why don't I have an ndk-build.exe anywhere on my machine when that script is specifically looking for that file?